# Allow internet access to intranet only users using Nginx on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to allow some users who only have access to the intranet to access one specific internet site. I'm doing this by using Nginx as a reverse proxy. To test this, I would like to block all internet access on my Ubuntu 12.04 system and to only have access to the reverse proxy address. I've tried blocking all outgoing connections using iptables, but that doesn't seem to be the right way to do this. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks